# How to rename jpg files in all folders within a main folder?

Tags: windows-10, window, rename, photos

The jpgs files's name would be the same as the folder that contain  them and if there is more than one, they would be renamed adding 1, 2, 3 and so on at the end..
Something like this:

```
folderA
  folderA1.jpg
  folderA2.jpg
folderB
  folderB1.jpg
  folderB2.jpg
```

Comment: You can do this in `cmd` with nested `for` statements: the outer with `/d /r` to scan the directories, and the inner to scan the files in each directory. You will need to use `set /a` in the inner loop to increment a variable initialised in the outer loop. Have you tried any of this?

Comment: I've never done any of this :c

Comment: I suggest you read up on it. We are not a script-writing service: what we do is help with difficulties encountered when writing scripts, but we can't do that if you haven't made any attempt yourself. This is a good [reference site](https://ss64.com/nt/) with examples, though it's not intended for tuition..

Comment: Rather than CMD, I'd encourage you pick up PowerShell. If you need someone to write a script for you, check out Fiverr.com where you can get custom work for relatively cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking to do this without writing a script yourself?  If you don't mind downloading and using a 3rd party tool, here are some options:

- https://github.com/andrewning/sortphotos  <- this is what I use, but there's a learning curve
- https://www.advancedrenamer.com/
- https://lifehacker.com/organize-your-photos-with-this-windows-app-1830383368
- http://lmgtfy.com/?q=tool+to+rename+photos :-)